# transform tf idf pandas dataframe into a tf idf matrix

Tags: python, pandas, tf-idf

How can I convert a the following pandas dataframe with the tf-idf score of each word in several documents into a matrix named "tfdif" so that I can implement for instance

`from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer`


`str = 'this sentence has unseen text such as computer but also king lord juliet'
response = tfidf.transform([str])`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to fit the `TfidfVectorizer` using the original raw documents before being able to use it to transform a new document.

If you cannot access the original documents you can always recover the [idf weights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf#Inverse_document_frequency_2) of each word by constructing a dictionary:

```
idfs[word] = log{(# documents) / (# documents where word has non-zero tf-idf weight)}
```

Later you can use that dictionary to calculate the tf-idf weights for the new sentence:

```
from collections import Counter
words = sentence.split()
s_tfs = Counter(words)
s_idfs = {word: idfs.get(word, 0) for word in words}
s_tfidf = {word: s_tfs.get(word, 0) * s_idfs.get(word, 0) for word in idfs.keys()}
```

Comment: thank you. By recovering the idf weights of each word you mean the idf weights of the new words in the test set, right? How does knowledge of the tf-idf weights of the test words help me classify them into a document?

Comment: Yes you need the tf-idf weights of the words in the test set. Regarding the second question I think you should read up some basic tutorial about text classification. But basically you use the original tf-idf weights in your training set to train a classifier then use it to classify the test document using its tf-idf weights.